# typescript declare module type alias with same name

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm trying to add ambient type declaration in *.d.ts file in a following way:

```
// .../src/myLib/index.d.ts

export type MyType = { field1: string }
```

```
// .../src/types.d.ts

import {MyType as MT} from "./myLib";

declare module "myLib" {
    export declare type MyType = MT & { field2: number }
}
```

However In a different file I cannot use:

```
import {MyType} from "myLib";

let x: MyType {
    field1: "myString",
    field2: 15,
```

I tried doing the same thing for the third party module as well.
for example:

```
import {NextPage as NP} from "next";

declare module "next" {
    export declare type NextPage = NP & { field2: number }
}
```

in `next` module `NextPage` is defined as type alias as well.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: does it help if you: *export* declare module "myLib" ... ?

Comment: unfortunately no :( it works if i change it to export declare type "MyTypes" instead of MyType. only way i could add extra property to NextPage, is to copy type definition of the NextPage and use that instead of "NP" in the last example.